# Using Miche pistard wheels with brakes?

Tags: brakes, wheels

I just bought a pair of Miche Pistard track wheels to upgrade my fixed gear bike. Stupidly, I did not consider that since the mainly are designed for track use, that they may not be designed for use with brakes. Will I ruin them if I try to use them with brakes?

I would be ok with some cosmetic damage if it’s still safe to ride...

Comment: I don't see how you could get brakes to work on them.

Comment: Could always replace the hub and frame and install discs. :)

Comment: +1 for asking and not blindly going ahead.  If you could add a clear photo of your new rims, showing the profile up close then that would help.

Answer (score 3):

I did some googling and don't see the answer spelled out specifically, which is typical for anything Miche.

Don't do it. It's reasonable to assume for a wheel like this, a racey track set with no visual indication of a brake track and with graphics where a brake track would usually be, that the wall thickness has nothing to give safely. For dedicated track wheels that's a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

"safe to ride" is a statement from authority.  We're random people on the internet who can't even see your wheel and are not qualified to make a judgement for you.

A rim designed for rim brakes will have a rim brake track.  If you don't have that, the rim is NOT intended for rim brakes, and won't have enough thickness.  A rim brake will initially work, but the touchpoint will wear quicker, and will have less thickness so you'll be risking a rim blow-off much sooner.

Its possible that you'll write off the rim in short order, maybe as little as 1000 km.
Or it may survive for a long time - we can't tell you what's "safe"   We're showing you the risks, its up to you to to make an informed decision as a competent adult after weighing the risks/benefit.

---

My advice would be to sell the track wheels on, and buy a suitable set of wheels used.

Its likely your track wheels are for a 120mm OLD, so using them in a road bike may require frame bending too, and then you're always going to need 120mm rear wheels.  Its just not worth it - buy some boring normal wheels which will be cheaper than uncommon track wheels.  You might even come out ahead financially.

Comment: More significant than durability is the fact that the rims are not flat on the sides, but slope inward rather dramatically.  This would mean that the brake pads would slide inward as more pressure was applied, causing, at best, bizarre braking behavior.

Comment: Adding to the problem with brakes, durability issues may arise as well. Tracks are usually flat and smooth while on roads there are cobbles, potholes grit and pebbles.